# How to parse the facebook like count data and echo it on the site

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have the following code which shows me the facebook like counts for that specific post.. How do i grab that data number and display it on the website?

```
<a href="http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://gunstons.com/mistakes-when-entering-into-a-sectional-title-scheme/'"></a>
```

This is what the code produces

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://gunstons.com/mistakes-when-entering-into-a-sectional-title-scheme/",
     "total_count": 2
      }
           ]
}
```

How do you grab the total count number and echo is on the site

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://gunstons.com/mistakes-when-entering-into-a-sectional-title-scheme/'"); //Grab the contents of the link
$data = json_decode($contents); //Parse the contents into a dictionary
echo $data->data->total_count; //Get the total count
?>
```

Hope this works!

Comment: `urlencode(..)` for the value of GET `q` would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://gunstons.com/mistakes-when-entering-into-a-sectional-title-scheme/'"></a>
```

I presume that you'd put that in an HTML that gets sent to the browser. That won't do you any good. Best it can get you is that when a user clicks on the link, the browser will open that page and show the ugly JSON to the user.

---

I believe you'd want to do the processing on the server side and sent the final count to the user. In that case, something like below will help.

```
<?php

$yourUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=";

#URL Encode is necessary!
$yourUrl .= urlencode("SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://gunstons.com/mistakes-when-entering-into-a-sectional-title-scheme/'");

$v = file_get_contents($yourUrl);
$obj = json_decode($v,true);
echo $obj["data"][0]["total_count"];

?>
```